# Página de comparativo de produtos

Tags: php, mysql, comparação

Criei uma página onde faço primeiro uma escolha em um `select/list` (gênero musical), depois dependendo da escolha aparece o segundo `select/list` (música) com opções relacionadas ao gênero.

O que eu preciso é que os itens que forem sendo escolhidos (músicas) sejam incluídos em uma lista abaixo para que eu possa em seguida fazer uma escolha para comparação (daquelas com mais detalhes), e cada um deles possa ser enviado (via email ou pro banco), através de um `checkbox` terminando assim o processo de escolha, comparação e envio.

Alguém poderia ajudar como fazer isso em PHP e MySQL?
Obs.: tenho os scripts iniciais, mas da lista na mesma página é que tá o enrosco... (tipo carrinho de compras só que na mesma página)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi seu problema é com javascript.

Eu recomendo utilizar uma biblioteca chamada [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Com o jQuery você pode fazer:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#id-do-select-musica').change(function(){
  // por convenção minha, se a variavel conter um objeto jQuery eu começo o nome 
  // dela com $
  var $opcaoSelecionada = $(this).find('option:selected');
  // você pode acessar o valor da option selecionada aqui
  console.log( $opcaoSelecionada.val() );
  //pode acessar o conteúdo do option selecionado também
  console.log( $opcaoSelecionada.text() );

  // Se quiser copiar a option pra outro select
  $opcaoSelecionada.clone().appendTo( $('#idDaListaDeMusicasSelecionadas') );

});
</script>
```

Recomendo aprender sobre o jQuery, é bem simples de usar e muito útil.

Sobre o seu comentário, eu te mostrei como pega os valores do atributo value da option selecionada com `.val()` e seu conteúdo textual com `.text()`.

Se você quer criar um checkbox com esses valores, pode escrever o checkbox em javascript mesmo e adicioná-los ao elemento que quiser:

```
// cria o checkbox que você quer colocar na nova lista
var meuCheckbox = '<input type="checkbox" value="'+$opcaoSelecionada.val()+'">';
// adicionar o checkbox ao div com id="meuDiv"
$('#meuDiv').append(meuCheckboc);
```

Você teria de colocar esse código dentro da funcão anônima que esta como parametro da funcão `.change` que eu escrevi acima.

Comment: Opa @Erik, realmente não conheço desenvolver algo com Jquery, só peguei alguns exemplos pronto e aproveitei em alguns códigos. Teria algum exemplo de na mesma página eu selecionar os itens (independente de select/list ou outra fonte) e ir criando a lista de escolhas abaixo? O problema para mim está na criação desta parte na mesma página, manter os dados e permitir escolhe-los por checkbox e enviar (por email ou banco). Obrigado!